Update array inside a while loop under db.transaction method
REACT NATIVE Doubt :
Tryint to read database and make an array of the content. In the code, after updating the Array 'rcpts', it remains null while trying to access outside the db.transaction block. How to really update the Array inside that block ? I ask bcz, it seems that the Array remains null or in its oringinal form even after update inside the while loop of db.transaction block.


let rcpts = []

const db = SQLite.openDatabase('digit.db');
//date, agentNo, custName, custNo, paidAmount, custBalance, payMode, revGroup FROM tblRcpt ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 100 
function pushreceipts(){  
  let rcptlist =[];
  //Alert.alert("you clicked");
    db.transaction(tx=>{
      tx.executeSql("SELECT id,date, agentNo, custName, custNo, paidAmount, custBalance, payMode, revGroup FROM tblRcpt ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 100 ",
        null,(tx,result)=>{          
          let len = result.rows.length;
          if (len>0){
            for(let i =0;i<len;i++){
              let item = result.rows.item(i);              
              rcptlist.push({
                rcptNo : item.id,
                rcptdate : item.date,
                agentNo : item.agentNo,
                custName : item.custName,
                custNo : item.custNo,
                paidAmount : item.paidAmount,
                custBalance : item.custBalance,
                payMode : item.payMode,
                revGroup : item.revGroup
              });
              i++;
            } 
          }
          rcpts = rcptlist;
          Alert.alert("Data Push finished.")
          //Alert.alert("Survey Added");
        }),
        (error) =>{
          Alert.alert(error);
        }
      }
    )
    // **** Read the rcps Array and send using fetch here. ****
    let qty = rcpts.length;
    let i = 0;
    console.log(rcpts.length)
    while(i<qty+1){
      console.log('length of rcpts array'+rcpts.length);

      i++;
    }

  

}




That's because you are trying to access before the request results. You are giving a callback, which is called once the query is done (promise), but you're trying to access the array before this callback is executed

@Mike, thank you. But could you please helo how to fix it ? Im new to react native

To answer your question ;
You are giving a callback, but trying to access the array without making sure your callback has been called. You might do something like this instead :
const db = SQLite.openDatabase('digit.db');

async function pushreceipts() {
  let rcpts = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql("SELECT id, date, agentNo, custName, custNo, paidAmount, custBalance, payMode, revGroup FROM tblRcpt ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 100 ",
        null, (tx, result) => {
          let len = result.rows.length;
          let res = [];
          if (len > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              let item = result.rows.item(i);
              res.push({
                rcptNo: item.id,
                rcptdate: item.date,
                agentNo: item.agentNo,
                custName: item.custName,
                custNo: item.custNo,
                paidAmount: item.paidAmount,
                custBalance: item.custBalance,
                payMode: item.payMode,
                revGroup: item.revGroup
              });
              i++;
            }
          }
          resolve(res);
        }),
        (error) => reject(error)
    }))
  // **** Read the rcps Array and send using fetch here. ****
  let qty = rcpts.length;
  let i = 0;
  console.log(rcpts.length)
  while (i < qty + 1) {
    console.log('length of rcpts array' + rcpts.length);
    i++;
  }
}


But, a more appropriate solution for what you are trying to do, would be to use Expo SQLite ;
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

const allRows = await db.getAllAsync("SELECT id, date, agentNo, custName, custNo, paidAmount, custBalance, payMode, revGroup FROM tblRcpt ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 100");
for (const row of allRows) {
  console.log(row.id, row.value, row.intValue);
}


Thank you @Mike for your time spent for me and the reply. It gave what i wanted.
